# Teamcity. Conditional builds trigger

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have two builds on Teamcity and these two builds are running on different build agents. Does anybody know how to set up the following configuration:

Build B has to start only if build A has a specific parameter set to TRUE.

I tried to make build B dependent on build A via Snapshot Dependencies and attach Finish Build Trigger to it with the parameter dep.., but this did not help - build B runs constantly